# Program never completes when loop is set to 4000000

Tags: python

```
fib1 = 1
fib2 = 2

i = 0
sum = 0

while i < 3999998:

    fibn = fib1 + fib2

    fib1 = fib2
    fib2 = fibn

    i += 1

    if fibn % 2 == 0:
        sum = sum + fibn

print(sum + 2)
```

The challenge is to add even Fibonacci numbers under 4000000. It works for small limits say 10 numbers. But goes on forever when set for 4000000.
Code is in Python

Comment: the numbers are huge, addition of such a huge numbers is slow, using `%` modulo is slow as well

Comment: You are finding `4,000,000` fibonacci numbers, not fibonacci numbers upto `4,000,000`. Change your loop condition to `while fib2 < 3999998`?

Comment: In Python, you can write `a, b = b, a + b`.

Comment: Also, if you are doing this for Project Euler (I don't want to tell exactly what is wrong), but your loop condition is checking the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are inefficiencies in your code, but the biggest one is that you're mistaken about what you're computing.

At each iteration `i` increases by one, and you are checking at each step whether `i < 3999998`. You are effectively finding the first *4 million fibonacci numbers*.

You should change your loop condition to `while fib2 < 3999998`.

A couple of other minor optimisations. Leverage python's swapping syntax `x, y = y, x` and its `sum` function. Computing the sum once over a list is slightly faster then summing them up successively over a loop.

```
a, b = 1, 2
fib = []
while b < 3999998:
   a, b = b, a + b
   if b % 2 == 0:
      fib.append(b)

sum(fib) + 2
```

This runs in `100000 loops, best of 3: 7.51 µs per loop`, a whopping 3 microseconds faster than your current code (once you fix it, that is).

Answer (score 2):

You are computing the first 4 million fibonacci numbers. It's going to take a while. It took me almost 5 minutes to compute the result, which was about 817 KB of digits, after I replaced `fibn % 2 == 0` with `fibn & 1 == 0` - an optimization that makes a big difference on such large numbers.

In other words, your code will eventually finish - it will just take a long time.

Update: your version finished after 42 minutes.

Comment: I've been thinking about a possibility to eliminate the division by taking advantage of the fact that only every third Fibonacci number is even: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... -> O, O, E, O, O, E, ...; Of course, testing the last bit is faster

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think that they simply stopped at Fib(2222). Not so much because calculating Fib(2223) is much work (to add 2 numbers with a few thousand digits can be done in much less than a second), but more because the next number is also just large and not very interesting.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I don't know where you got that Fib(2222) is the largest fibonacci number. It's not true.

Comment: @Ronald Good observation. You could even just move three positions at once with `a, b = a+2*b, 2*a+3*b`. Then `b` will go through all the even Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Hmm, what Python version did you use and what CPU? I just tried `a, b = 1, 2` followed by `for _ in range(4000000): a, b = b, a+b` and that already took 32 minutes on my fairly fast PC. So I'm surprised you took less than 5 minutes for doing more work. I used CPython 3.6.4 on an otherwise idle i7-6700 CPU.

Comment: That code took 3 minutes in python 3.6.4 on my laptop with a i7-3520M. I'm guessing the speed difference could be in the arbitrary precision integer implementation. I've seen similar speedups by switching implementation. Not sure what python uses, but I have gmp version 6.1.2 installed.